# Как лучше хранить и передавать статичную структуру каталога и подкаталога товаров? ArrayList или БД?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, arraylist, cursoradaper

Делаю приложение - каталог товаров.

Надо сделать два ListView, в первом мы будем выбирать тип, во втором - подтип товара, в третьем View будет список товаров. Я сделал для них свои ArrayAdapter-ы, но как их хранить и сделать доступными из любого fragment?
Есть для этого какие-то глобальные переменные? Если я создаю и наполняю

```
public class catalogFragment extends Fragment {     
public static final List<CatalogClass> Catalog = new ArrayList<CatalogClass>();
...
```

то как мне сделать этот CatalogClass Catalog видимым в следующей Activity/Fragment? Стоит использовать для хранения структуры каталога базу данных и CusorAdapet, и обращаться к ней в нужном месте, или можно всё организовать через какой-то файл и подключать его в нужные фрагменты?

Comment: по моему опыту SQLite, дает очень быстрые показатели при работе, я использовал его в приложении, с огромным кол-ом исторических данных и картинками, с возможностью изменять информацию динамически. Можете посмотреть если есть желание: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shwarz.application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Однозначно для этой задачи подойдет только использование базы данных в качестве хранилища данных. К ней можно выполнять запросы на получение только части данных. Так же, при больших объемах данных, использование курсора или различных ORM, которые предоставляют `LazyList`, позволит избежать `OOM` ошибки.

В будущем использование бд упростит загрузку какой либо детальной информации о записи - достаточно будет передать id записи в следующий Activity/Fragment, и сделать выборку по этому id.

Ну и плюс ко всему для работы с бд существует множество ORM которые упростят и ускорят разработку.

Answer (score 0):

В классе наследника `Fragment`не рекомендуется хранить данные, так как его жизненный цикл не постоянен. Данные лучше вынести в классы модели и обращаться к ним по необходимости.
Если данных много, то лучше хранить в локальной базе данных (SQLite) и обращаться к ней через `CursorAdapter`.
Если данных не много, можно хранить в `SharedPreference`

И еще, по правилам оформления кода Java класс должен начинаться с Большой буквы. Хотя конечно вам никто не запрещает назвать его с маленькой.